# Pentaho bi server (ce) JDBC connect with parameters

Tags: java, jdbc, pentaho, business-intelligence

I would like to use JDBC connection paramters - when setting a new datasource. I.e. here:
(Instead of using constant values)

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/topic/config_ba_server/images/ssbaPdiDialogConnect.png

How can I use them (syntax)? (${db_host} ? @db_host ?etc)

Also,
can I use such parameters from a mondrian cube ? I.e. set which db host/ db user dynamically from the cube (parameters files ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For JDBC Connectivity, simply give the database details like :

```
Host: 10.230.45.12; 
db name: mydb ; 
port: 1521
user: user_name; 
password: passwd
```

And for Mondrian cube, try reading [this link](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fanalysis_guide%2Ftopic_prd_analysis.html).

Comment: I would like it to be parameterized, each time I would like to connect to other host with other pass.

Comment: In pentaho report, i assume you cannot parametrize a db connection like pentaho etl... If possible try using jndi connection in prpt !!! (Note : i haven't tried this step myself. Just a suggestion)